Adding complex objects in .NET Core
These are my entities:
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
    [Required]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmployeeID")]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    ...
    public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    // public long Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public long OrderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderID")]
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public long Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Discount { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

I need to implement AddOrderAsync and UpdateOrderAsync methods. I have tried a lot of variants but getting different types of errors like

System.InvalidOperationException : The instance of entity type 'Category' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'CategoryId'} is already being tracked.

public async Task<long> AddOrderAsync(RepositoryOrder order)
{        
    var entityOrder = order.ToEntityOrder();
    this.context.Orders.Add(entityOrder);

    // Add the order details
    foreach (var detail in order.OrderDetails)
    {
        this.context.OrderDetails.Add(detail.ToEntityOrderDetail());
    }

    // Save changes
    await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Commit transaction
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
    return entityOrder.OrderId;
}
public static EntityOrder ToEntityOrder(this Order order)
{
    return new EntityOrder()
        {
            OrderId = order.Id,
            CustomerId = order.Customer.Code.Code,
            Customer = new EntityCustomer()
            {
                CustomerId = order.Customer.Code.Code,
                CompanyName = order.Customer.CompanyName,
            },
            EmployeeId = order.Employee.Id,
            Employee = new Entities.Employee()
            {
                EmployeeId = order.Employee.Id,
                LastName = order.Employee.LastName,
                FirstName = order.Employee.FirstName,
                Country = order.Employee.Country,
            },
            OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
            RequiredDate = order.RequiredDate,
            ShippedDate = order.ShippedDate,
            ShipVia = order.Shipper.Id,
            Shipper = new Entities.Shipper()
            {
                ShipperId = order.Shipper.Id,
                CompanyName = order.Shipper.CompanyName,
            },
        };
    }

public static EntityOrderDetail ToEntityOrderDetail(this OrderDetail repositoryOrderDetail)
    {
        return new EntityOrderDetail()
        {
            OrderId = repositoryOrderDetail.Order.Id,
            Product = new Entities.Product()
            {
                ProductId = repositoryOrderDetail.Product.Id,
                ProductName = repositoryOrderDetail.Product.ProductName,
                SupplierId = repositoryOrderDetail.Product.SupplierId,
                Supplier = new Entities.Supplier()
                {
                    SupplierId = repositoryOrderDetail.Product.SupplierId,
                    CompanyName = repositoryOrderDetail.Product.Supplier,
                },
                    CategoryId = repositoryOrderDetail.Product.CategoryId,
                    Category = new Entities.Category()
                    {
                        CategoryId = repositoryOrderDetail.Product.CategoryId,
                        CategoryName = repositoryOrderDetail.Product.Category,
                    },
                },
            ProductId = repositoryOrderDetail.Product.Id,
            UnitPrice = repositoryOrderDetail.UnitPrice,
            Quantity = repositoryOrderDetail.Quantity,
            Discount = repositoryOrderDetail.Discount,
            };
        }


Remove foreach loop.

Please provide more detail about where you use Category and its relations, I think the issue is where you create the RepositoryOrder.

I have provided all methods above.

The exception is pretty clear: you're adding multiple Category entity objects with the same CategoryId. Why do you set Category while setting CategoryId would suffice?

You need to be "very aware" of distinct/unique objects.  Let me take a simpler example.  A "Department" can have many "Employee"(s). An "Employee" has a single parent "Department".  When I am adding or updating many Employees in a single execution, I can add the many emp-s, BUT if all those employees have the same parent Department (and let's say it is a new Department), those many employees must REFERENCE the SAME "instantiated Dept". You cannot keep adding a "new" emp.ParentDepartment over and over again. You'll create the new single Department one time, and  ref that Dept over and over.

A slightly different way to think about it.  EF is a little "dumb", in the sense it will (try to) do EXACTLY what you tell it to do.  Take the Department/Emp example.  If I add 2 emps, and "new up" each "emp.ParentDepartment" with the same DeptKey/DeptName, (thus I have TWO Department that have the same values)... EF will try to add TWO departments with the same values, and thus fail on a PK/distinct issue.  BUT, if I create a single Dept (and add to dbContext) and then REFERENCE that single Dept on each of the 2 new employees (and add these 2 emps to the dbContext), it should work.
